# nodejs function call export modue how to get function parameter dynamically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, dynamic, arguments

I want to get arguments from function in nodejs.

I already try this code in nodejs

```
var mainArguments = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

It's doing well javascript but not my nodejs.

here is my code.

```
const service = require('../service/service');
service["joinRoom"](io, socket, params.sellerGroup);
// call function joinRoom
```

service.js

```
joinRoom : (io, socket, room) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var mainArguments = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        log.debug(mainArguments);
        log.debug("excute service :: joinRoom");
        socket.join(room);
        resolve(true);
    });
}
```

the log main arguments are

> - '1':
>     { [Function: require]
>       resolve: [Function: resolve],
>       main:
>        Module {
>          id: '.',
>          exports: {},
>          parent: null,
>          filename: 'C:\Project\socketManager.js',
>          loaded: false,
>          children: [Object],
>          paths: [Object] },
>       extensions: { '.js': [Function], '.json': [Function], '.node': [Function] },
>       cache:
>        { 'C:\Users\lee\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\ProcessContainerFork.js':
>     [Object],
>          'C:\Users\lee\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\pmx\index.js':
>     [Object],
>          'C:\Users\lee\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\pmx\lib\pmx.js':
>     [Object],
>          'C:\Users\lee\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\pmx\lib\events.js':
>     [Object],
>          'C:\Users\lee\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\debug\src\index.js':
>     [Object],

like this.

I think the code

```
var mainArguments = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

not working.

so anyone has a good idea for me?

thank you for you help.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want, you just want to get argument on a function like "function (args1, args2) {}" or get a value from the function like "return x" ?

Comment: From what function do you want arguments?

Comment: i just want to call a function with dynamic paramters.
if i have two function and one thiing needs a parameter and another thing nees two parametes.

Comment: You can do it. What function though? You use `mainArguments` only for debugging.